# Volume bounded between to multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Really would like some pointers on how to attack this! I understand how to find the integrand, but how do you get the bounds?. The correct answer is Choice B.

[image]

Comment: Calculate the intersection, that'll give the domain you should be integrating over.

Comment: Yes, I did that and solved for y and got y = sqrt(2-(1/2)x^2) which is not present in any of the bounds. However, it is equal to the bounds in choice B...but why would they write it like that??

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$. Then the limits are $F(x,y)-2 \leq z\leq 6-F(x,y)$, such that $2F(x,y)\leq 8$ and therefore, $F(x,y)\leq 4$. Let's notice that $x^2+2y^2 \leq 4$, and therefore, $y^2 \leq \frac{4-x^2}{2}$, and therefore, $-\sqrt{\frac{4-x^2}{2}}\leq y \leq \sqrt{\frac{4-x^2}{2}}$. On the other hand, since, $x^2\leq 4$ as well, then $-2\leq x\leq 2$. Therefore this is the integration range, and since $F(x,y)-2\leq z\leq 6-F(x,y)$ on this range, then we have to calculate $6-F(x,y)-(F(x,y)-2)=8-2F(x,y)=8-2x^2-4y^2$ on this range.

Comment: Reasoning for making F(x,y) = x^2 + 2y^2? Where did this come from?

Comment: I noticed that the boundaries are $x^2+2y^2-2\leq z \leq 6-(x^2+2y^2)$ and therefore, $F(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$ was a natural choice since it appears in the limits of $z$ on the requested region.